# Checking for a particular data constructor

Tags: haskell, types, typechecking

Let's say that I defined my own data-Type like

```
data MyData = A arg| B arg2| C arg3
```

How would I write a function (for instance: `isMyDataType`) that checks wether the given argument is one out of the particular types in `MyData` and successively returns a boolean (True or False) , e.g. typing in Ghci: 
`isMyDataType B` returns True and `isMyDataType Int` returns False.

Comment: Haskell is typed statically. This means, that all type-system related issues are to be figured out at compile time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe you want functions to test for particular **constructors**:

```
isA :: MyData -> Bool
isB :: MyData -> Bool
```

If so, then you can write these yourself or derive them.  The implementation would look like:

```
isA (A _) = True
isA _     = False

isB (B _) = True
isB _     = False
```

To derive them automatically, just use the [derive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/derive) library and add, in your source code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Data.DeriveTH

data MyData = ...
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show}

derive makeIs ''MyData
-- Older GHCs require more syntax: $( derive makeIs ''MyData)
```

Also note: your data declaration is invalid, the name must be capitalized, `MyData` instead of `myData`.

Finally, this whole answer is based on the assumption you want to test constructors, not data types as you said (which are statically checked at compile time, as Tarrasch said).

Comment: Yes i meant it that way TomDM.

Comment: Is there a more updated answer to this since derive is no longer in stackage?

Comment: This answer pre-dates stackage.  Perhaps a you should add a non-stackage package to your project?  I know there are ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell always checks that the types makes sense. The compiler would complain immediately if you wrote `isMyDataType 4`, because `4` is not of type `MyData`, it's of type `Int`.

I'm not sure this is what you asked for, but either way I strongly suggest for you to try out what you've asked here in practice, so you can see for yourself. Most important is that you check out **type signatures** in haskell, it is key for learning haskell.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Maybe`s. You can create a set of functions that check for each of the types

```
getA, getB, getC :: MyData a -> Maybe a
getA x = case x of {(A v) -> Just v; _ -> Nothing}
getB x = case x of {(B v) -> Just v; _ -> Nothing}
getC x = case x of {(C v) -> Just v; _ -> Nothing}
```

This affords some practical idioms for certain tasks:

```
allAs :: [MyData a] -> [a]
allAs xs = mapMaybe getA xs

printIfA :: Show a => MyData a -> IO ()
printIfA x = maybe (return ()) print $ getA x
```