# Haskell: Filter set based on member type?

Tags: haskell, set, subset

Let's say I have the following data structure in Haskell to represent a Checkers
/Draughts piece:

```
data Piece = Reg {pos :: Square, color :: Color}
         | King {pos :: Square, color :: Color}
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Given a list of these `Pieces`, how might I isolate the `King`s from the list? I've been looking at the documentation for `Data.Set` at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/containers-0.5.0.0/Data-Set.html but couldn't find something that seemed obvious to me.

In short, I need a method that will, given a `Data.Set` set of `Piece`, return the subset of all `King` type pieces. I feel like it's something very simple but that I haven't encountered yet because I'm new to the Data.Set class in Haskell.

Comment: Why not do `data PieceType = Reg | King` and `data Piece = Piece { pieceType :: PieceType, pos :: Square, color :: Color }`?

Comment: Then you can just filter on the value of that field: `filter ((== King) . pieceType)`.  Obviously you'd want to derive `Eq` for this

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088935/checking-for-a-particular-data-constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a Boolean function `isKing` and then use `filter` in `Data.Set`, as follows:

```
import Data.Set as S
data Color = Int deriving (Show, Eq)
data Square = Square (Int,Int) deriving (Show, Eq)
data Piece = Reg {pos :: Square, color :: Color}
         | King {pos :: Square, color :: Color}
    deriving (Show, Eq)

isKing King{} = True
isKing _ = False

getKings s = S.filter isKing s
```

Comment: `isKing King{} = True` lets you avoid changing `isKing` if the number of fields changes.