# How to avoid writing trivial data type check functions

Tags: haskell

Some of my data types in Haskell end up having quite a few records, for example

```
data MyData
  = A Int Int String Float Int (Char, Char)
  | B Int String Float (Char, String) String
```

and to check what type it is I end up writing functions like

```
isA :: MyData -> Bool
isA (A _ _ _ _ _ _) = True
isA _ = False

-- isB and so on
```

Now this gets cumbersome fairly quickly so I searched how to use `derive` or something similar to auto-generate those and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088935/checking-for-a-particular-data-constructor). However, the [library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/derive) proposed in that question seems to be out of date due to the introduction of [ghc generics](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics) and the related [generic-deriving library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving). I've taken a look at these but they seem to be very powerful and I don't quite know where to start.

So my question is: How can you (if possible) get around having to manually write `isA` and `isB` for `MyData`?

Comment: Relevant Reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/74r611/deriving_is_functions/. Although… I’m not sure what about those makes the library you’ve already found out of date?

Comment: The fact that its build status is 'failed' and the comment right beneath that. Maybe it is not accurate to call it "out of date" tough, I'm not sure.

Comment: This looks interesting: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/is-0.4/docs/Data-Generics-Is-TH.html

Comment: Would it help if you would write it this way: `data MyData = A (Int, Int, String, Float, Int, (Char, Char)) | B (Int, String, Float, (Char, String), String)`?

Comment: Tangential note: while this is an entirely reasonable question, you might want to double-check whether and how often you actually need the boolean tests. For instance, an `if isA x -- etc.` check can generally be replaced with pattern matching on `x` (say, with a `case` expression).

Comment: @duplode That's fair. However, I personally don't like to write a lot of "_" when pattern machting types with multiple records and this would be a way around that.

Comment: @Elmex80s Not really, the example is just chosen to illustrate that I have data types with many records that are annoying to pattern mach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Record syntax can be exploited for this.

```
isA :: MyData -> Bool
isA A{} = True
isA _   = False
```

This requires no extensions, and works regardless of the number of parameters constructor `A` takes.

(That being said, I don't think such functions are that useful in Haskell. Beware of "boolean blindness" -- i.e., of reducing information to booleans when you do not need to.)

Comment: Okay, then maybe I'll try to avoid this altogether, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

So one way that circumvents the mindless writing of a lot of type check functions is to use [this library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/is-0.4/) (found in the Reddit [Ry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ry) posted - thanks!).

Example code:

```
import Data.Generics.Is.TH

-- Cumbersome
printType (A _ _ _ _ _ _) = putStrLn "Is A"
printType (B _ _ _ _ _) = putStrLn "Is B"

-- With library
printType x
  | $(is 'A) x = putStrLn "Is A"
  | $(is 'B) x = putStrLn "Is B"
```

Instead of `isA` and `isB` you would simply write `$(is 'A)` or `$(is 'B)` which works fine for me.

Comment: What is the benefit of this over using your original `isA :: MyData -> Bool` function?

Comment: 2 advantages: First, you don't need to manually define a function for each type (A, B and what not) and second when you add/remove a record of a type later on you won't need to add/remove a "_" in the corresponding type check function.